# Get Current user's AD Groups InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Currently I am having a requirement to get Active Directory Group List for current logged in user.

I tried with :

> /_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx
>
> /_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx

I am only able retrieve SharePoint Groups.

Quick reply will be high appreciated as this an urgent FIX.

Thank you

Comment: Is this SharePoint Online or SharePoint on-premises? If on-premises, which version?

Comment: on-premises and 15.0

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not provide a web service to get Active Directory group information. The only way I'm aware of to get this information in InfoPath is for you to create a custom web service that would provide it.

If you wish to build the custom web service then you should be able to use code similar to the code below to get the `UserPrincipal` for the current user. Once you do you can call the `GetGroups` method to find out the groups to which they belong.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;  

protected bool CurrentUserIsMemberOfGroup(string groupName)  
{  
    string userLogin = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;  
    // To get the right context, run with elevated privileges  
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()   
    {  
        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);  
        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType.SamAccountName, userLogin);  
        var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext , groupName);  
        return userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(group);   
    });  
}
```

For more information on getting information from Active Directory please see [Check if a SharePoint user is member of an AD group](http://www.sharepointpills.com/2011/09/check-if-sharepoint-user-is-member-of.html), 
[Retrieve the Active Directory groups of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126746/retrieve-the-active-directory-groups-of-the-current-user), and [UserPrincipal Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For more information on building and deploying a custom web service please see [Building a SharePoint-Hosted WCF Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rje25vBQEDA)

Comment: Thank you rob, Are we able get Distribution List Group in this way? So far I have seen only AD groups not Distribution Groups..confusing!